C# NLog add rule doesn't seem to work for some reason
I am trying to block some not needed Microsoft debug logs in my app. I have a separate settings file where nLogLevel is set as either info or debug depending what my settings say. When nLogLevel is set as info everything works as intended. But when it is set as debug, those Microsoft debug logs are being logged, even though I say here that minlevel should be always info.
// Rules for mapping loggers to targets.
loggingConfiguration.AddRule(nLogLevel, LogLevel.Fatal, logDb);
loggingConfiguration.AddRule(nLogLevel, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);

loggingConfiguration.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, logDb, "Microsoft.*");
loggingConfiguration.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile, "Microsoft.*");

Am I missing something really obvious here or should I do ruling differently?
NLog version numbers are

NLog.Database="5.2.8"
NLog.Extensions.Logging="5.3.8"


Check the bin folder in the project and make sure the executable in the debug folder and release folder the dates are current.  It sound like you are not recompiling both the debug and the release executables.

Notice the order of NLog Logging Rules are important. Any rules for filtering away unwanted logger-output should be added first. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

This is a little tricky. For Nlog, you need to config "all levels" from "Microsoft.*" to go to somewhere. The rule
loggingConfiguration.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, logDb, "Microsoft.*");

will let "Info, Warn, Error, Fatal" levels go to "logDb".  But where would "Trace, Debug" go?
Apparently, "Trace ,Debug" will following your first global rule, which let "Debug" also go to "logDb".
You could try following sample to make clear understanding
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(config);

var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget("console");
//this target write to nowhere
var nullTarget = new NullTarget("null");
config.AddTarget(consoleTarget);
config.AddTarget(nullTarget);

//You need to set tartget for all levels  within "Microsoft.*", true flag means this rule will not be override
config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Debug,nullTarget, "Microsoft.*",true);

config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, consoleTarget, "*");

builder.Logging.ClearProviders(); // Clears default logging providers.
builder.Host.UseNLog(); // Use NLog as the logging provider.


Notice when using NLog v5, then one can use the Fluent Configuration API. Example:
LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(c =>
{
   c.ForLogger("Microsoft.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Warn);
   c.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(nLogLevel).WriteTo(logDb);
   c.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(nLogLevel).WriteTo(logfile);
});

Where WriteToNil rely on FinalMinLevel-option, that was also introduced with NLog v5.
